# Convert pandas index to date format for sorting

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe (df) with a type string index:

```
                   0
Jan 2021    0.852144
Jan 2022    0.442388
Feb 2021    0.406946
Feb 2022    0.296960
       :           :
Nov 2021    0.829171
Nov 2022    0.601725
Dec 2021    0.214810
Dec 2022    0.673403
```

How do I convert the index to type datetime so I can sort the df to look like:

```
                   0
Jan 2021    0.686585
Feb 2021    0.214810
Mar 2021    0.852144
Apr 2021    0.920720
       :           :
Sep 2022    0.770413
Oct 2022    0.751213
Nov 2022    0.601725
Dec 2022    0.924836
```

Answer (score 2):

For smae format like original only sorted values use [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) with `key` parameter:

```
df = df.sort_index(key=lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x))
```

If need DatetimeIndex and then sorting ouput is different:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df = df.sort_index()
```